# Include routed groups for authenticated url

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

Include routed groups for authenticated url.

I need to create authentication groups and enable the routes according to the permissions.

For example.

```
urlpatterns = [
    @adminGroup
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    @userGroup, @adminGroup
    path('/home', home.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: Guess you want something like [django-decorator-include](https://pypi.org/project/django-decorator-include/) with [user_passes_test decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test)

Answer (score 0):

We can make use of the [**`staff_member_required`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#the-staff-member-required-decorator) and [**`login_required`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) functions.

In order to enforce the decorator on a group of urls, we can use [**`django-decorator-include`** [GitHub]](https://github.com/twidi/django-decorator-include).

You can install this with:

```
$ pip3 install django-decorator-include
```

(probably in your virtual environment)

We can then enforce the decorators with:

```
from decorator_include import decorator_include
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.admin.views.decorators import staff_member_required

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', decorator_include(staff_member_required, 'admin.site.urls')),
    path('/home', decorator_include(login_required, 'home.site.urls')),
]
```

For more complex tests, you can use [**`user_passes_test`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test).

Comment: Hi. Thank you. How can I use groups?

Comment: Yes, for example `decorator_include(user_passes_test(lambda u: u.groups.filter(name='my_group_name').exists())`, 'home.site.urls')` for example.

Comment: Use name__in if more than one group?

Comment: @marcelo.delta: yes, but note that it is sufficient that the user belongs to *one* of the listed groups, not *all*.

Comment: Hi, could you help one more time? How can I use the decorator in this URL? path(r'modulo/cadastro/cliente',             ClienteList.as_view(),     name='cadastro_list'),

Comment: I figured out how to do it. Thank you